# First publication of first-order language with function symbols

Tags: logic, reference-request, first-order-logic, math-history

What was the first publication of a first-order language that included function symbols, such as the functors of language B of Carnap’s *Einführung in die symbolische Logik* (1954)?

Function symbols seem to have become commonplace by the mid 1960s -- e.g, Shoenfield's *Mathematical Logic* (1967) -- but not earlier.

Comment: Not necessarily voting to close yet, but this feels like it might fit better on [hsm.stackexchange.com](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Oh, [hsm.stackexchange.com](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) sounds more appropriate. Should I delete my question here?

Comment: IMO they are already present into Hilbert-Bernays 1934 and also Gentzen.

Comment: And in Herbrand 1930? On page 526 of _From Frege to Gödel_, van Heijenoort says "In Chapter 3 [of his thesis] Herbrand calls any system a _theory_ if it is obtained from his system of Chapter 2 by the adjunction of some of the following: (1) Function letters (called _descriptive functions_ and intended to represent in the system functions from individuals to individuals) together with an extended rule of existential generalization, ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Mauro ALLEGRAMZA](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/108274/mauro-allegranza) suggested, function symbols ("Funktionszeichen") are introduced in [1], along with the notion of a term. This is a translation by Google Translate from pages 186-187 of the 1968 edition:

> Now the mathematical function signs - we say simply "function signs" -
> are to be introduced as a new kind of symbols. As a function sign we
> generally take, i.e., unless some special common symbol is used,
> lowercase Greek letters. The function signs differ from the predicate
> symbols in the formalism in that a predicate symbol provided with
> arguments forms a formula (namely a prime formula), whereas a function
> sign provided with arguments forms a "term", where "term" from now on
> should be the common designation for such expressions that can be used
> for a free individual variable. The insertion rule for the free
> individual variables now receives an extension. As terms, i.e. for
> substitution for the free individual variables, [are] admitted:
>
> 1. Free individual variables;
> 2. Individual symbols;
> 3. Function characters whose argument places are each either through is a free individual variable or is filled by an individual symbol;
> 4. Expressions obtained by, starting from an expression of the third kind (with at least one free variable occurring in it), once or
>    repeatedly applying the process of replacing a free individual
>    variable by an expression of the third kind.

According to Heijenoort [2], "In Chapter 3 [of his thesis] Herbrand [3] calls any system a theory if it is obtained from his system of Chapter 2 by the adjunction of some of the following: (1) Function letters (called descriptive functions and intended to represent in the system functions from individuals to individuals) together with an extended rule of existential generalization, ...".

In his 1920 paper [4] (translated to English in [2]), Skolem says:

> It is now easy to carry out the proof of Theorem 2. Let a first order
> proposition in normal form,
>
> $$\forall_{x_1} \ldots \forall_{x_m} \exists_{y_1} \ldots
> > \exists_{y_n} U_{x_1…x_m y_1…y_n}$$
>
> be given, and let us assume that it is satisfied in a given domain for
> certain values of the relative symbols occurring in $U$. By the
> principle of choice we can then, for every choice of $x_1, \ldots,
> > x_m$, imagine a definite sequence chosen from among the corresponding
> sequences $y_1, \ldots, y_n$, that is the sequences $y_1, \ldots, y_n$
> for which $U_{x_1 \ldots x_m y_1…y_n}$ is true. We can appropriately
> denote by
>
> $$y_1(x_1, \ldots, x_m), y_2(x_1, \ldots, x_m), \ldots, y_n(x_1,
> > \ldots, x_m)$$
>
> or, more briefly, by $y_1(x), y_2(x), \ldots, y_n(x)$, the sequence of
> the $y$ that correspond to the sequence $x_1, \ldots, x_m$. Then the
> proposition
>
> $$U_{x_1 \ldots x_m y_1(x) y_2(x) \ldots y_n(x)}$$
>
> holds for every choice of $x1, \ldots, x_m$. ...

[1] David Hilbert and Paul Bernays.  *Grundlagen der Mathematik*. 1934.

[2] Jean van Heijenoort. *From Frege to Gödel*. 1967.

[3] Jacques Herbrand. *Reserches sur la théorie de la démonstration*. 1930.

[4] Thoralf Skolem. "Logisch-kombinatorische Untersuchungen über die Erfüllbarkeit oder Beweisbarkeit mathematischer Sätze nebst einem Theoreme über dichte Mengen", 1920.